# Static IP on both devices and router

Tags: router, static-ip

I am trying to set up a new router with mostly static IPs for devices always on the network. I know how to set up static IPs on devices and the router, but wondering if I can do both. Can I set both devices to do static or should I only do one?

Edit: Because it was asked here is a network map

Comment: @tradisjames You haven’t provided the network map.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use DHCP, but configure host "Reservations" that automatically give a given box the same IP every time. the process for doing this will vary by router, but you will need the host MAC address and the IP you wish to give it. the hosts would be configured for DHCP. That is essential, or you lose all the benefits of this approach, so why bother to configure the router at all?

The reason most organizations do this, is because it allows you to centrally manage your IPs and still enjoy all the benefits of static addressing (save one). It lets you see all your assigned IPs so you can make decisions about new addresses, or completely revamp your layout from one place (or two if you use DNS). With static addressing, you have to visit each host to modify it.

There is only one notable downside to reservations; what happens if the DHCP server is offline? In that case, you can replace or repair your DHCP server, and reboot the machine to get an IP.

Comment: Ok, but I am wondering about configuring static on both router and device at the same time?

Comment: I believe I addressed that in my post. I would not recommend doing what you suggest, as it eliminates any benefits of registering it at the router at all, so you would in that case, be best off just statically configuring the servers and not touch the router at all. All you are doing by double-configing it is creating a mystery you have to solve 2 years later when you try to change something, it doesn't work, and you can't remember what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do both, you can have your router reserve certain DHCP addresses for some devices and also have those devices request an static IP, your router won't complain, however if for some reason your DHCP configuration changes you will have the problem of colliding addresses. So, in short, it's not recommended to use both methods at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but that isn't the most elegant solution.

It is simpler to use the DHCP/Reservations solution. As mentioned, if your DHCP server is down then you have to correct it to get an IP.  You should have a failover DHCP server which would pick up the work should your primary be offline.  That would solve the "can't find the DHCP server" issue.  (If both of them are offline, then that's the urgent issue to solve.)

Your detail does not mention network specifics and I am assuming you use your own DHCP server, not one located at an ISP.